# Excel to Word Find and Replace - How to bypass 255 Character Limit

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a table with the list of words to be replaced with on a word document and used this code below. It worked perfectly until recently I got an error saying "String Parameter Too Long" ie beyond 255 characters. Can someone please fix this for me?

My knowledge on coding/VBA is zero and I haven't put in the time to learn it as I only need to be on word processing.

The word document is name as **doc** within **folder** on the desktop.
The excel sheet is named as **book** within **folder** on the desktop.

Thanks a lot.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open "/Users/NAME/Desktop/folder/doc.docx"
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A

                .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  'Replacements from col B

                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False

                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            Next
        End With
        .Quit SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Add code to split source column into 2 columns when > 255

Comment: Can you please help me with that? I'm clueless

Answer (score 0):

One way is to copy the replacement content to the clipboard. For example:

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, wdDoc As Object, itm As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("/Users/NAME/Desktop/folder/doc.docx")

        With wdDoc.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
                itm.Offset(, 1).Copy  'Replacements from col B
                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A
                .Replacement.Text = "^c"
                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            Next
        End With
        .Quit SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Excel's Data -> Text to Column -> Fixed Width option to split the lengthy columns and then replace them with the same code I questioned with. But the best way would be to fix the code and go with copying the replacement content to the clipboard. as suggested by @macropod