Can content in Word that exceeds 255 characters be replaced?
I have a script to fill out a Word template document with information. It replaces tagged parts (e.g. <>) in the Word doc with data from Excel.
The problem I am running in to is with this section:
With wDoc.Content.Find
            .Execute FindText:="<<ad>>", ReplaceWith:=ad, Replace:=2
End With

Here I get a

Run-time error 5854 - string parameter too long

As far as I understand it, this is because the find and replace funtion in Word doesn't like it when the replace data is over 255 characters long.
Is there a different way of going about this to bypass the character limit?

Does this solution work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745757/16578424?

Instead of using your own "tags" like <<ad>>, why aren't you doing it the proper way with Merge Fields?

It can be a solution:
  Dim r As Word.Range, i As Long
  Set r = wDoc.Content
  i = 2 ' repetitions to f&r
  While r.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<ad>>") And i > 0
    r.Text = ad
    i = i - 1
    r.End = wDoc.Content.End
  Wend

Use this code fragment as a replacement of what is in the question. Don't miss to replace "<<ad>>" with the proper variable name. Also, 'ad' variable's value is expected to be renewed for every new tag.
The idea here is to find the token then set the necessary text directly to the found range.
The test (run in Word):
Sub FR()
  Dim r As Word.Range, i As Long
  Dim find, repl, j As Long
  Dim wDoc As Document
  Set wDoc = ThisDocument
  find = Array("<<ad>>", "<<bc>>")
  repl = Array("==buirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuher uhbuirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuher uhbuirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuher uhbuirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuher uhbuirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuher uhbuirsdfg iuhuierhf aesgh iuhewr iuhiuhe==261", _
    "==jfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowerer hkjfgsjkerfg iouhwuioerg iuoohuiosdrg iuohiuoh uiowere==787")
  For j = LBound(find) To UBound(find)
    ' the solution code is below this line
    Set r = wDoc.Content
    i = 2 ' repetitions to f&r
    While r.find.Execute(FindText:=find(j)) And i > 0
      r.Text = repl(j)
      i = i - 1
      r.End = wDoc.Content.End
    Wend
    ' the solution code is above this line
  Next
End Sub



I have tried to put this in, and it will work for the first of my variables, hwoever when I add in the code again, changing the tags for the other 25 variables I want to replace, it does not register them, only replacing the first one on the list.

"only replacing the first one" - I guess you missed to replaced "<>" in FindText:="<<ad>>" with the proper variable name.

The test result is provided.

Here are two approaches.
This first approach just does a straight Find/Replace, copying the Excel cell's content to the clipboard, then using the ^c replacement parameter to insert the clipboard contents at each found match.
Sub WordFindAndReplace()
Dim xlSht As Worksheet, xlCell As Range, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1: Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2
Set xlSht = ActiveSheet: Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("File Path\Document.docx")
  With wdDoc.Range.Find
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Replacement.Text = "^c"
    For Each xlCell In xlSht.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
      xlCell.Offset(, 1).Copy  'Replacement string in col B
      .Text = xlCell.Value2    'Find string in col A
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
  .Quit SaveChanges:=True
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing
End Sub

This second approach loops through the document, directly inserting the Excel cell's text at each location. It's slower but avoids using the clipboard and allows you to do more work on the replacement strings (e.g. formatting) as you go.
Sub WordFindAndReplace()
Dim xlSht As Worksheet, xlCell As Range, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Const wdFindStop As Long = 0: Const wdCollapseEnd As Long = 0
Set xlSht = ActiveSheet: Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("File Path\Document.docx")
  For Each xlCell In xlSht.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    With wdDoc.Range
      .Find.Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Find.Text = xlCell.Value2        'Find string in col A
      Do While .Find.Execute
        .Text = xlCell.Offset(, 1).Text 'Replacement string in col B
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
    End With
  Next
  .Quit SaveChanges:=True
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing
End Sub


Using both methods here, I get a run-time error 5854 at
.Text = xlCell.Value2
and
.Find.Text = xlCell.Value2
saying that the string parameter is too long.
Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Just how long are the text strings you are trying to find? And how long are the text strings you are trying to replace?

The strings to find vary between 6 and 9 characters. The text I want to replace it with can be as long as ~300 characters.

Try replacing xlCell.Value2 with xlCell.Text

That still throws up the same error

I'm not getting an error. Do you have any content in column A or B in Excel other than the text to be found? If so, on what row do the Find/Replace strings begin?
